# Transpose of the adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, network

As homework, I had to construct an adjacency matrix for the following graph:

[image]

My solution was the following:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
  0&0&1&0&0 \\
  1&0&0&1&0 \\
  0&1&0&1&0 \\
  0&0&0&0&0 \\
  1&0&1&0&0 \end{bmatrix} $$

That means:

- vertex v1 shows to v3
- v2 shows to v1 and v4
- etc.

However, the correct solution was the following adjacency matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
   0&1&0&0&1 \\
   0&0&1&0&0 \\
   1&0&0&0&1 \\
   0&1&1&0&0 \\
   0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} $$

So, the transpose of my matrix is the correct solution. Unfortunately, I can't reach my lecturer over the weekend.

Could anyone please explain why my answer is wrong?

PS: When you enter the following string into [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) `1->3, 2->1, 2->4, 3->2, 3->4 ,5->1 ,5->3 directed graph`, you get the graph above, which is basically my matrix.

Comment: I think the adjacency matrix for a directed graph is one of those topics for which the author must declare which orientation is to be followed ("a matter of convention").  For what it's worth, your answer seems to agree with the convention stated in the [Adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) Wikipedia article.  There the *i*th row has the entries corresponding to edges leaving the *i*th node (and ending at nodes corresponding to the column indexes).

Comment: @hardmath: Maybe I used the incidence matrix, instead of the adjacency matrix?

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  While the adjacency matrix is necessarily square ($n\times n$ where $n$ is the number of nodes, the [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) is $n\times m$ where $m$ is the number of edges.  Probably best to check with the lecturer (or grader) after the weekend.

Comment: Both answers are correct in terms of $A$ describing the connectivity, just the numeric representation of $A$ is subject to a convention on what rows and columns mean.